# what is the difference betweeen "accumulation" and "aggregation"

Tags: differences

I looked up meriam webster and the two definitions seem to semantically  largely overlap. 
the only thing hinting towards the existense of  distinctness between the two terms,
seemed to be:  that the term "aggregation" is claiming certain qualities from the collection of elements. It doesn't suffice to have a group of elements to call them aggregation, there also has to be some other quality inherent to such a collection...

but since I'm far away from being a native speaker, 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I thank all three of you for the answers. 
I would have liked to accept more than one but this does not seem possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think etymology can help understand the original differences between the two terms. As you rightly pointed out *aggregation* refers mainly to a total considered with reference to its constituent parts; (see the Latin origin of the term):

> Examples: an aggregation of believers, of isolated settlements, of species.

*accumulation* refer more to a collection of several things grouped together or considered as a whole.

> Examples: an accumulation of capital, of energy; of evils; of fortunes; of honours;  of knowledge,  of power; of snow; of waters; of wealth; of wrath.

[accumulation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=accumulation&searchmode=none)(n.)

> late 15c., from Latin accumulationem (nominative accumulatio) "a heaping up," noun of action from past participle stem of accumulare "to heap up, amass," from ad- "in addition" (see ad-) + cumulare "heap up," from cumulus "heap" (see cumulus).

[aggregation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Aggregate&searchmode=none) (n.)

> early 15c., from Middle French agrégation or directly from Medieval Latin aggregationem (nominative aggregatio), noun of action from past participle stem of Latin aggregare (see aggregate (adj.)).
>
> *aggregate* (adj.)
> c.1400, from Latin aggregatus *"associated," literally "united in a flock," past participle of aggregare "add to (a flock), lead to a flock, bring together (in a flock)," from ad- "to" (see ad-) + gregare "herd" (see gregarious).*

Answer (score 2):

Accumulation of 1, 2, and 3: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. From the result (a number), you can't get back the original elements.

Aggregation of 1, 2, and 3: a list of elements 1, 2, and 3. From the result (a list), you can get back the original elements.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there's an overlap, but the words have different flavors.

To me, "accumulation" (as in "cumulative") seems more about gathering an increasing number of similar objects: accumulation of wealth, awards etc.

"Aggregation" (as in "gregarious") has more of a connotation of gathering of not necessarily similar objects: as in aggregation of qualities, of accounts etc. It also seems to have a hint of actual spatial proximity ("aggregation of blood platelets" as Google showed me) of the objects being aggregated.

Comment: would you say that "spatial proximity" is a quality non-inherent to "accumulations" ? the "not necessarily similar objects" aspect is nice

Answer (score 1):

Accumulation means acquisition or gathering over time, or it is used to refer to the mass that is gathered. Aggregation means gathering different parts together into a unified whole, or it is used to refer to the whole that has been gathered. Both refer to gathering things into a mass, accumulation implies a gradual acquisition over time; aggregation implies a gathering of distinct parts.

"The bucket accumulated two liters of rain water over the course of the week"

"I've aggregated everyone's research into an essay"

Comment: could you elaborate onto "unified whole" ?

Comment: By 'unified whole' I mean one consolidated piece.

Comment: what I would like to know is: are there any qualities justifying the perspective of such a collection as a "unified" / "consolidated" "whole". because I hope to find there an answer my mind can accept.

Comment: like for example do certain new qualities emerge in a collection of objects termed "aggregate" that the aggregated objects did not already have. and are these qualities more complex than just the results of repetition: like augmentation of certain measures.